# Use type from another global module but with similar submodule

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I work on a project where I need to export typings for two different Java libraries (I have my reasons) whose class hierarchies look like so.

`` libName
 `-namespace1
   `-Class1 // full class Name: (libName.namespace1.Class1)
    -Class2 // full class Name: (libName.namespace1.Class2) ``

and the other one:

`` org
 `-libName
   `namespace123
    `-Class1 // full class Name: (org.libName.namespace123)
      `public method1(param0: libName.namespace1.Class1): void ``

base.d.ts:

```html
declare module libName {
  export module namespace1 {
    export class Class1 {
      /* omitted for brevity */
    }
    export class Class2 {
      /* omitted for brevity */    
    }
  }
}

declare module org {
  export module libName {
    export class Class1 {
     public method1(param0: libName.namespace1.Class1): void
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, attempting to compile the above will result in `error TS2305: Module 'org.libName' has no exported member 'namespace1'` because the TSC assumes I intend to use the module declared in the same module.

Is there a way to work around this limitation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both of them in a common parent:

```
declare module wrapper {
  export module libName {
    export module namespace1 {
      export class Class1 {
        /* omitted for brevity */
      }
      export class Class2 {
        /* omitted for brevity */
      }
    }
  }

  export module org {
    export module libName {
      export class Class1 {
        public method1(param0: wrapper.libName.namespace1.Class1): void
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That can't do unfortunately, as I need to use the full qualifier without the `wrapper` part...

Comment: Ok. Where is this supposed to run? Is it for a browser? node?

Comment: This will run on top of V8, but a wrapper that requires the user to append something else, before the actual namespace is a no go.

Comment: Inside a browser the top level namespaces live inside the `window` object, so they are automatically wrapped. Maybe you can do that same with the node `global` object, I've never tried it.

Comment: Callbacks for top-level namespaces like `org` and `libName` are generated automatically. To prepend anything, will just break that logic and invalidate it, because of TS's limitations...

Comment: The limitations are of javascript and not typescript. Unfortunately you probably won't have a way to get it to work